# VMFS undelete in ESX4i

Tags: vmware-esx, vmware-esxi, vmfs

So, I have this friend that deleted a VMDK that had all his family photos on it. ESX4i did not prompt him that the disk was in use, and he thought he was deleting a disk that belonged to another VM. He is ready to spend the block recovery fees from one of the data recovery firms. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I hope your friend (and everyone else viewing this question) learned that you do-not-delete-stuff-from-the-datastore-unless-you're-10000%-sure

Comment: ...or at least 200% :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has he used the [vmdk-undelete tool](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1007243) before? if so then he could use that, otherwise he may well be out of luck.

Edit - sorry, didn't realise this doesn't work with v4.

Edit2 - there's an outside chance that [this](http://www.virtualizationteam.com/virtualization-vmware/vmware-vi3-virtualization-vmware/vmware-esx-how-to-recover-your-vmfs-partition-table.html) could help but it's very SC-specific rather than being vMA/'unsupported'-specific.

Comment: Yeah, I think he ended up paying the data recovery fees. It was his home lab, and it was either the wife spending the money to hide his dead corpse, or spending the money on the data recovery.

Answer (score 0):

If "only" the photos are important, [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) is a good tool.